# pi camera V2.1 digital zoom

Tags: camera, raspbian-stretch, picamera

The Rpi camera V2.1 is 8-megapixel that mean it's maximum resolution is 3266 x 2450. I would like to record a video in 720P resolution using this camera.

My question is.. maximum how much I can do crop or zoom that image will remain undistorted in 720P resolution?

Also, how can I achieve that means what is the procedure of zooming?